# Why was my question about integral binary quadratic forms removed?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

The title of the question is *probably*:

Relations between fractional ideals of an order of a quadratic number field and binary quadratic forms

Comment: I have undeleted it. Surely we don't want automated deletion of questions of such high pedigree (Gauss).

Comment: @BillDubuque Thanks. Another question called "A binary quadratic form and an ideal of an order of a quadratic number field" was also removed. I'd be grateful if you undelete it.

Comment: Gauss has an account on MSE?! (And is above normal procedures?)

Comment: @Hurkyl The question was down voted for no proper reason.
You know that.

Comment: @Makoto: *If* true, then *that* is a reason to undelete. The stated reason is absurd.

Comment: @Hurkyl My question was down voted because some people had ill feelings toward me for some reasons which had nothing to do with the question. You know that.

Comment: @Bill: I find it questionable to undelete an automatically deleted questions, but fine with that. Why on earth did you undelete a question that was **deleted by three community members**? I thought that you disagreed with the idea that moderators should act *against* three/five votes from the community. Or is it only when you are against deletion and closure?

Comment: @Asaf Deletion should be reserved for content that has no place here such as spam. Neither of those questions meet that criteria. We all know what occurred back then. There is no reason to reopen that can of worms since these problems have all been solved (or, at least, compromises have been reached that keep the peace in the community).

Comment: @Bill: Deletion of content should be reserved for content that three high reputation members have agreed which should be deleted. I was one of the original deleting votes, and I still think that this should be deleted. I think that **regardless** to the identity of the OP. I think that that post was very unfitting to this site, and I was not the only who thought that, it seems. I don't see why a moderator which keep promoting "let the community do its work" is so anxious to override something **done by the community**.

Comment: @Bill: Had you polled the three deleting members for their reasons, I would have agreed that *maybe* there is a very very slim chance to consider overriding that decision. I would have *never* expected it to come from you (although you did override votes in the past and canceled them as "political votes", even when that was not the case). I'm not even sure why you did that, you were only request to undelete two posts which were deleted automatically. Not that one.

Comment: @Asaf You are welcome to share your opinions on why you think these questions should be deleted, as is anyone. For such an extreme action there had better be very good reasons backing it up. No such reasons have been given by anyone. I doubt they exist.

Comment: @Bill: The point is that I have witnessed you zealously support the idea that only unanimous moderator decisions should allow a moderator to take action; and you have zealously promoted the idea that moderators should **never** (except in the case of spam, or so) remove content or close content. I even recall you advocating against *final* vote since it too is binding. Suddenly you no longer care. You undelete, a **closed** question which was deleted **by three members**, without discussing it with anyone, nor bringing it to the meta.

Comment: [cont] I don't care, I couldn't care less, after all your speeches over emails and previous discussions, that **you** see no reason for that question to be deleted, or closed, or whatever. It was closed and deleted **honestly** by the community. Undoing what users did democratically is an action which I see no less than offensive when coming from your hands. It is not only that I care that you deleted or undeleted. it shows that all those things you said are just words, words which you refuse to back in the moment you see fit.

Comment: @Asaf Please do give your reasons for thinking that these questions require the extreme action of deletion.

Comment: @Bill: Please don't twist my words. I did not claim that any of the two automatically deleted questions should have been deleted, although I would probably be reluctant to undelete them on my own. I do think that a question polling for opinions whether or not the mathematical community should use a different notation for families because *someone* (who's admitting not to be a professional mathematician) found it confusing. I think that such idea should be brought up on a blog, not here. It has absolutely no *correct* answer, and it makes little sense, if any, to ask it on a site like this.

Comment: Er, shouldn't it be the other way around? Shouldn't questions that have had a successful vote to delete require a good reason to undelete? Shouldn't questions that have satisfied the criteria that indicate a question is poor enough to be autodeleted require a good reason to undo that behavior?

Comment: Why delete it? The broken windows theory. Other people will see that we do allow for *some* discussion. I don't want other people to come to this site and say "Oh, that bloke wrote a question similar to this, I'll try to write something similar as well".

Comment: @asaf I see no "broken windows". Rather I see two interesting number-theoretical questions about binary-quadratic forms - questions that would occur to many students studying these topics; questions whose answers could add very valuable content to the site.

Comment: @Bill: Read **again**. While my complaints about undeleting the automatically deleted questions are debatable, this is not what I am talking about. Stop bring it up already. This is getting off-topic, and you are being impossible to discuss with. This is just like sitting in **Room 12A**.

Comment: @Asaf When, and *only when,* you provide some *strong* reasons why you think these questions should be deleted, will I be happy to continue this discussion.

Comment: @Bill: I have provided my reasons for deletion, of course you have dismissed them because this is not "spam" in any way. Yes, you and I have very different visions for this site. What is unclear to me, is how someone so libertarian can act so much like a tyrant. If you think that the community should manage itself without interference, I would call undeleting a question closed by five, and deleted by three members without **any** moderator intervention an act of tyranny. I had some hopes that at least you were loyal to your own agenda, but apparently that is my mistake.

Comment: @Bill: And yet, twice as many people found them worthy of downvotes, and neither managed to attract any answers, and was even voted to be deleted. By taking unilateral action *for the reasons you state*, you are saying that the community doesn't matter, nor does empirical reality matter: only your opinion matters.

Comment: @Hurkyl I have yet to see *anyone* supply any thoughtful *rational* argument why those questions should have been deleted (or even downoted). Do you have one or not?

Comment: @Bill: Nope. That's why I have not been making arguments that they should be deleted, nor did I vote to delete (I think), nor did I program the autodeleter. I have yet to see you supply a thoughtful, *rational* argument that they should have been undeleted. Do you have one or not?

Comment: @Hurkyl I already stated that in my [second comment above.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6354/why-was-my-question-about-integral-binary-quadratic-forms-removed#comment22409_6354)

Comment: So if I ask a question "Was Gauss an antisemitic person?" that would be a good question as well? (I would have voted to close and delete such question, by the way.)

Comment: @Bill: ... but since you've made me think about it, yes I do have a thoughtful *rational* argument why the questions should have been deleted. The purpose of the "vote to delete" option is for people with high reputation and presumably good judgement with the site's best interest in mind can collectively judge a post worthy of deletion, and a quota of such users have weighed in their opinion. Similarly, the other post was judged poorly by the community, and passed a threshold that has been previously set to warrant auto-deletion. In neither case has a reasonable reason been to go against it.

Comment: @Bill: Gauss did not write the MSE question: Makoto did. And even if Gauss did write a MSE question that the community decided was worth deleting, then it should still be deleted even though Gauss wrote it. If you think there is a truly interesting question to be written that would be valuable to the site, then go write it, rather than try to tell the community that the question they condemned is that question.

Comment: @Hurkyl Sorry, that does not count as a thoughtful rational argument why either of those posts deserve deletion. The comment I linked to explaining my reasons said nothing about Gauss (the remark about Gauss was, of course, tongue-in-cheek, in case that was not clear).

Comment: @Hurkyl: For Bill it seems that the only rational argument for deletion is "spam" or "Bill decrees so". As this case is neither, I think that any further time wasted on this discussion is fruitless. I have began process for closing and deleting the now undeleted questions (now I *do* have a reason to delete the autodeleted ones -- Hurkyl's argument is wonderful).

Comment: @Bill: It wouldn't count in a brand new meta post on the topic of "should these questions be undeleted?", but it sure counts *here*. What do you think the purpose of "vote to delete" privilege and the auto-deleter are?!?!

Comment: Just as I surmised, neither of you are able to give any good reasons supporting these bizarre unprecedented deletions. As such, as far as I'm concerned, nothing more needs to be said on the matter. I have no interest in arguing for the sake of argument.

Comment: @Bill: The topic of this discussion has been that of unilateral acts of moderation. If you really think the deletions were bizarre then why not open a meta post on the topic? Isn't that the *usual* manner in which such differences of opinion are supposed to be handled?

Comment: @Hurkyl Please read my prior comment. It is quite serious.

Comment: @BillDubuque But you also didn't provide a reason to undelete a deleted question, even when you (as Asaf witnessed) said that you wouldn't/couldn't do that. The point Asaf tried to state is **only** about this controversy but you're trying to use an alternate escapist question to make their decision invalid (which constitutes a fallacy) - when the reason for undoing the deletition is the only thing that matters. You should first answer this question.

Comment: @Gustavo Please see the [companion thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/6362/242) where there is further details (but also much confusion).

Answer (score 16):

Your question has had negative score and no answers for more than a month: it gets automaticaly deleted by the software.

Comment: Thanks. I should have written the answer then. I have no idea why it was down voted.

Comment: For reference on the auto-deleter: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006